# How to map over a CommentedMap while preserving the comments/style?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

Given a `ruamel.yaml` `CommentedMap()`, and some transformation function `f: CommentedMap →  Any`, I would like to produce a new `CommentedMap` with transformed keys and values, but otherwise as similar as possible to the original.

If I don't care about preserving style, I can do this:

```py
result = {
    f(key) : f(value)
    for key, value in my_commented_map.items()
}
```

If I didn't need to transform the keys (and I didn't care about mutating the original), I could do this:

```py
for key, value in my_commented_map.items():
    my_commented_map[key] = f(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style and comment information are each attached to the
`CommentedMap` via special attributes.  The style you can copy, but
the comments are partly indexed to key on which line they occur, and
if you transform that key, you also need to transform that indexed
comment.

In your first example you apply `f()` to both key and value, I'll use
seperate functions in my example, all-capsing the keys, and
all-lowercasing the values (this of course only works on string type
keys and value, so this is a restriction of the example, **not** of
the solution)

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap as CM
from ruamel.yaml.comments import Format, Comment


yaml_str = """\
# example YAML document
abc: All Strings are Equal  # but some Strings are more Equal then others
klm: Flying Blue
xYz: the End                # for now
"""

def fkey(s):
    return s.upper()

def fval(s):
    return s.lower()

def transform(data, fk, fv):
    d = CM()
    if hasattr(data, Format.attrib):
        setattr(d, Format.attrib, getattr(data, Format.attrib))
    ca = None
    if hasattr(data, Comment.attrib):
        setattr(d, Comment.attrib, getattr(data, Comment.attrib))
        ca = getattr(d, Comment.attrib)
    # as the key mapping could map new keys on old keys, first gather everything
    key_com = {}
    for k in data:
        new_k = fk(k)
        d[new_k] = fv(data[k])
        if ca is not None and k in ca.items:
            key_com[new_k] = ca.items.pop(k)
    if ca is not None:
        assert len(ca.items) == 0
        ca._items = key_com  # the attribute, not the read-only property
    return d

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

# the following will print any new CommentedMap with curly braces, this just here to check
# if the style attribute copying is working correctly, remove from real code
yaml.default_flow_style = True

data = transform(data, fkey, fval)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# example YAML document
ABC: all strings are equal  # but some Strings are more Equal then others
KLM: flying blue
XYZ: the end                # for now
```

Please note:

- the above tries (and succeeds) to start a comment in the original
  column, if that is not possible, e.g. when a transformed key or
  value takes more space, it is pushed further to the right.
- if you have a more complex datastructure, recursively walk the tree, descending into mappings 
  and sequences. In that case it might be more easy to store `(key, value, comment)` tuples 
  then `pop()` all the keys and reinsert the stored values (instead of rebuilding the tree).